# Saving Excel File with File Name from Within

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am using following Script to Convert ".xls" file into ".xlsx". I want to change the file name of the newly converted file to a cell value found in cell "G9" of each worksheet. Please suggest the change in the script so file name could be changed to cell value at "G9".

```
Option Explicit

Dim oFSO, myFolder
Dim xlText

myFolder="C:\Users\khawar\Downloads"


Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xlText = 51 'Excel Text format enum
Call ConvertAllExcelFiles(myFolder)
Set oFSO = Nothing

Call MsgBox ("Done!")


Sub ConvertAllExcelFiles(ByVal oFolder)
Dim targetF, oFileList, oFile
Dim oExcel, oWB, oWSH

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set targetF = oFSO.GetFolder(oFolder)
    Set oFileList = targetF.Files
    For Each oFile in oFileList
        If (Right(oFile.Name, 4) = ".xls") Then
            Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)     
            oWB.ActiveSheet.Name = "Data"
            For Each oWSH in oWB.Sheets
                Call oWSH.SaveAs (myFolder & "\" & oWB.Name & ".xlsx", xlText)
            Next
            Set oWSH = Nothing
            Call oWB.Close
            Set oWB = Nothing
        End If
    Next
    Call oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `Call oWSH.SaveAs (myFolder & "\" & oWB.ActiveSheet.Range("G9") & ".xlsx", xlText)`

Comment: Thanks @nightcrawler23